# How do I loop through one dataframe and find value from another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to calculate `KendallTau` distance of two lists for which I intend to use the `scipy` library.

I have two csv files as inputs, each with the same attributes:

```
attr1, attr2,..., attrN.
```

Assume the first file has data:

```
attr1  attr2  attr3  attr4  attr5
1      a      //some value that I don't care 
2      b      //ditto
3      c      //
4      d      //
```

The second file has this data

```
attr1  attr2  attr3  attr4  attr5
1      d      //some value that I don't care 
2      a      //ditto
3      c      //
4      b      //
```

My goal is to get two 1D arrays as input to the `KendallTau` library method. 
I want my first array to be `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and my second to be `[2, 4, 3, 1]`.

That is loop through each element in `attr2` in list 1 and find it's corresponding `attr1` in list 2.

So the values of `[a, b, c, d]` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in list 1 and `[2, 4, 3, 1]` in list 2.

My problem is how do I loop through and find the values in the list? How to I dynamically look up value of a from another list?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Are you simply looking to find `attr1` value of common values in `attr2`?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` can `join` two data frames:

```
data = data1.join(data2)
```

then the columns can be turned into lists if needed:

```
values1 = list(data['attr1'])
values2 = list(data['attr2'])
```

You can get your data into a dataframe with:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

sample data used:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame([
    (1,      'a'),
    (2,      'b'),
    (3,      'c'),
    (4,      'd'),
], columns=('attr', 'attr1')).set_index('attr')

data2 = pd.DataFrame([
    (1,      'd'),
    (2,      'a'),
    (3,      'c'),
    (4,      'b'),
], columns=('attr', 'attr2')).set_index('attr')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, just do the following:

First, merge the two tables but discarding all of the attributes you don't care about.

```
df = data1[['attr1', 'attr2']].merge(data2[['attr1', 'attr2']], on = 'attr2', how='outer', suffixes = ['dat1', 'dat2'])
```

This merger will align common `attr2` values in both tables. As a result, you will have `attr1_dat1` and `attr1_dat2`columns containing precisely the lists you are seeking.

If you still want them in lists, just do:

```
list1 = df.attr1_dat1.to_list()
list2 = df.attr2_dat2.to_list()
```

though why you would want that befuddles me since you can just index the `df`.